# Export to XML then to Excel (to make the export faster)

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

hi i want to export an `entity framework` query to excel if i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel , it takes about 3 minutes . is there any other method to export the query to excel faster?
by the  way i have to manipulate query info in loop while creating excel worksheet.

thank you.

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel? using Automation or Drivers?

Comment: @A9S6: He said `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Answer (score 0):

you need to find where the "slowness" come in.

have you try changed the program to output to simple text file? is it as slow as export to Excel?